# Grouped line charts using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset like this:

[DataSet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emhou.png)

DataSet can be found here: https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2013/crime-in-the-u.s.-2013/tables/1tabledatadecoverviewpdf/table_1_crime_in_the_united_states_by_volume_and_rate_per_100000_inhabitants_1994-2013.xls

And i want to plot line chart containing line for every crime rate by year.
Something like this:
[Crime Rate graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RtFH.png)
But the graph shows continuous years on x-axis like 2005.5 2007.5.
Any one can help? or suggest a better approach to do this. Thanks

and here is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py
import seaborn as sns

cd =pd.read_clipboard() #after copying the dataset from given url above


        yearRate = cd[['Year','ViolentCrimeRate','MurderRate','RapeRate','RobberyRate','AggravatedAssaultRate','PropertyCrimeRate','BurglaryRate','LarcenyTheftRate','MotorVehicleTheftRate']]
    # These are the "Tableau 20" colors as RGB.    
    tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120),    
                 (44, 160, 44), (152, 223, 138), (214, 39, 40), (255, 152, 150),    
                 (148, 103, 189), (197, 176, 213), (140, 86, 75), (196, 156, 148),    
                 (227, 119, 194), (247, 182, 210), (127, 127, 127), (199, 199, 199),    
                 (188, 189, 34), (219, 219, 141), (23, 190, 207), (158, 218, 229)] 
    for i in range(len(tableau20)):    
        r, g, b = tableau20[i]    
        tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)  


    plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

    plt.ylim(0,5000)
    plt.xlim(1994, 2013)

    plt.yticks(fontsize=14)  
    plt.xticks(fontsize=14)  

    for y in range(0, 5000, 1000):    
        plt.plot(range(1994, 2013), [y] * len(range(1994, 2013)), "--", lw=0.5, color="black", alpha=0)

    rates=['ViolentCrimeRate','MurderRate','RapeRate','RobberyRate','AggravatedAssaultRate','PropertyCrimeRate','BurglaryRate','LarcenyTheftRate','MotorVehicleTheftRate']

    for rank, column in enumerate(rates):    
        # Plot each line separately with its own color, using the Tableau 20    
        # color set in order.    
        plt.plot(yearRate.Year.values,yearRate[column.replace("\n", " ")].values,lw=2.5, color=tableau20[rank])    
        # Add a text label to the right end of every line. Most of the code below    
        # is adding specific offsets y position because some labels overlapped.    
        y_pos = yearRate[column.replace("\n", " ")].values[-1] - 0.5    
        if column == "MotorVehicleTheftRate":    
            y_pos -= 50 
        elif column == "MurderRate":    
            y_pos -= 50 
        plt.text(2013, y_pos, column, fontsize=14, color=tableau20[rank])
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Especially it would be nice to have some copy-pastable code.

Comment: @ArcoBast
    You want me to paste the code here or dataset?

Comment: Can you edit it in your original post such that I just can copy and paste the code and it runs immediately?

Comment: Sorry, this copy-pasting step doesn't work for me. Maybe you want to check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to copy the data set from the provided link(it will be saved in clipbaord): https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2013/crime-in-the-u.s.-2013/tables/1tabledatadecoverviewpdf/table_1_crime_in_the_united_states_by_volume_and_rate_per_100000_inhabitants_1994-2013.xls

and then run the code, read)clipboard() will load data from the clipbaord

Comment: Yeah tried that but it did not work. If you can shrink your code down such that it is minimal and self containing I would give it a try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
plt.xticks(cd['Year'])
```

solved the issue.